# Blend textures of different size/coordinates in GLSL

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, blending

If blending two textures of different size in the fragment shader, is it possible to map the textures to different coordinates?

For example, if blending the textures from the following two images:

[image: black and white mask image] [image: Matterhorn image]

with the following shaders:

```
      // Vertex shader
      uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
      attribute vec4 vPosition;
      attribute vec2 aTexcoord;
      varying vec2 vTexcoord;
      void main() {
        gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
        vTexcoord = aTexcoord;
      }

      // Fragment shader
      uniform sampler2D uContTexSampler;
      uniform sampler2D uMaskTextSampler;
      varying vec2 vTexcoord;
      void main() {
        vec4 mask = texture2D(uMaskTextSampler, vTexcoord);
        vec4 text = texture2D(uContTexSampler, vTexcoord);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(text.r * mask.r), text.g * mask.r, text.b * mask.r, text.a * mask.r); 
      }
```

(The fragment shader replaces the white spaces of the black and white mask with the second texture).

Since both texture use the same gl_Position and coordinates (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), both texture get mapped to the same coordinates in the view:

[image]

However, my goal is to maintain the original texture ratio:

[image]

I want to achieve this within the shader, rather than `glBlendFunc` and `glBlendFuncSeparate`, in order to my own values for blending.

Is there a way to achieve this within GLSL? I have a feeling that my approach for blending texture vertices for different position coordinates is broken by design...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is indeed possible but you need to get a 2D scale vector for the mask texture coordinates. I suggest you to compute those on the CPU and send them to the shader via uniform, alternative is to compute them per vertex or even per fragment but you will still need to pass image dimensions into the shader so just do it on the CPU and add an uniform.

To get that scale vector you will need a bit of simple math. What you want to do is respect the mask ratio but scale it so one of the 2 scale coordinates is `1.0` and other is `<=1.0`. That means that you will either see the whole mask width or height while the opposite dimension will be scaled down. For instance if you have an image of size 1.0x1.0 and a mask of size 2.0x1.0 your scale vector will be (.5, 1.0).

To use this `scaleVector` you simply need to multiply the texture coordinates:

```
vec4 mask = texture2D(uMaskTextSampler, vTexcoord* scaleVector);
```

To compute the scale vector try this:

```
    float imageWidth;
    float imageHeight;
    float maskWidth;
    float maskHeight;

    float imageRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight;
    float maskRatio = maskWidth/maskHeight;

    float scaleX, scaleY;

    if(imageRatio/maskRatio > 1.0f) {
        //x will be 1.0
        scaleX = 1.0f;
        scaleY = 1.0f/(imageRatio/maskRatio);
    }
    else {
        //y will be 1.0
        scaleX = imageRatio/maskRatio;
        scaleY = 1.0f;
    }
```

Note I did not try this code so you might need to play around a bit.

**EDIT: Scaling the texture coordinates fix**

The above scale of texture coordinates makes the mask texture use the top-left part instead of centre part. The coordinates must be scaled around centre. That means get the original vector from centre which is `vTexcoord-vec2(.5,.5)` then scale this vector and add it back from the centre:

```
vec2 fromCentre = vTexcoord-vec2(.5,.5);
vec2 scaledFromCenter = fromCenter*scaleVector;
vec2 resultCoordinate = vec2(.5,.5) + scaledFromCenter;
```

You can put this into a single line and even try to shorten it a bit (do it on the paper first).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This got me on the right track - scaling turned out easy with a vec2 variable, now I'm working on managing the position of the mask.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that part, you have it on the left side now... You need to normalise it around .5. Let me edit.

Comment: Try this edit, I hope it is correct... And do NOT change the positions, those should be the same as the target. Also note you might be able to do the scaling in vertex shader and add another texture coordinate for the mask in fragment shader.

Comment: @MaticOblak just wanted to say thanks. This is the single most useful post I've found for working with size/position in fragment shaders. I'm working in a system right where I only have access to frags (no vertex or extraneous openGL methods) and this information saved my life.